# Problems integrating an Add to Google Wallet button with Flutter

Tags: flutter, wallet, google-wallet

I am using the [flutter_google_wallet](https://pub.dev/packages?q=flutter_google_wallet) plugin to add an Add to Google Wallet button to my app. In the process I've made several mistakes that I wasn't able to figure out without contacting Google's developer support for [Google Pay and Wallet console.](https://pay.google.com/business/console/profiles)

Some of the error message I dealt with during the process were:

- "Something went wrong. Please try again"
- "Validate RPC failed"
- "Unable to load this pass"

I did not find solutions to these issues online, so I'll document them in an answer to this "question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first attempt at using the plugin resulted in getting an error displayed that said:
"Something went wrong. Please try again" and in the adb log I saw an error which said "Validate RPC failed". Support indicated that I needed to get my app added to their "allow-list" by sending them my Issuer ID, App package name, and SHA1 fingerprint. After sending Google this info, it was a couple days before they let me know that I could proceed.

The documentation for the flutter_google_wallet shows that you pass a json string to its savePasses method but it doesn't show an example of that string, so you have to dig around the google documentation for that format. Initially, I was just sending the "payload" value without wrapping that in an element that included the iss, aud, typ, iat, and origins properties.

The next error I made was in copying my issuerId from the Google Pay Console.  Don't confuse your alpha-numeric merchant ID for your issuerId.  The issuerId should be only digits such as: 3388000000012345678.  You'll find this at the center of the Google Pay & Wallet console page near the center top after it says Google Wallet API
Issuer ID:.  This value gets used in two places in your json. The first is as a prefix to your object's "id" value. The second place is as a prefix to the object's "classId" value.

I was specifying the "iat" value in the wrong format. It should be a numeric "unix_time" (seconds since epoch) value.

Another error I ran into was that one of the images I referenced had been moved. If you are using a heroImage property, double check and make sure the URI is valid.

The final mistake I realized I had made was that I was trying to use a "genericObjects" payload with a classId that was an "Event Ticket" type.  Make sure to use "eventTicketObjects" json with "Event Ticket" type classes and "genericObjects" with "Generic" type classes!

Although eventually, I'll create this json on a server, I'm currently mocking that out and creating it within my Flutter app using the code below:

```
    // "email address" that google created for your "service account" which you can 
    // find on https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
    const issuerEmail = 'google-wallet-my-proj@company-proj.iam.gserviceaccount.com';

    // update this with the issuerId found on pay.google.com/business/console
    const issuerId = '3388000000012345678';

    // name of Google Wallet class you created on pay.google.com/business/console
    const className = 'GeneralAdmission';
    final passId = const Uuid().v4(); // random uuid

    final iat = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
    final json = '''
{
    "iss": "$issuerEmail",
    "aud": "google",
    "typ": "savetowallet",
    "iat": "$iat",
    "origins": [],
    "payload": {
        "genericObjects": [{
            "id": "$issuerId.$passId",
            "classId": "$issuerId.$className",
            "genericType": "GENERIC_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED",
            "cardTitle": {
                "defaultValue": {
                    "language": "en",
                    "value": "Card title"
                }
            },
            "header": {
                "defaultValue": {
                    "language": "en",
                    "value": "header"
                }
            },
            "subheader": {
                "defaultValue": {
                    "language": "en",
                    "value": "subheader"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
''';
```

Comment: Hello, John. I'm using the web version and now experiencing this issue with "Something went wrong. Please try again." Please how do I check my logs? And how do I contact support regarding this?

Comment: update: the issue was with my token being more than 1800 in length as specified here https://developers.google.com/wallet/generic/web#:~:text=encoded%20JWT%20is-,1800%20characters,-.%20If%20your%20JWT

Comment: Glad you figured that out!  The link to get support from Google is on the Google Pay and Wallet Console page for your merchant account at https://pay.google.com/business/console/home/YOUR_MERCHANT_ID

Comment: @EvidenceEkanem I'm facing the same error "Something went wrong. Please try again" when ever i tried to load the jwt token over mobile browser. My JTW token length is more than 1800 characters.  I'm using Google Wallet Objects java library to create the jwttoken. Any idea how we can solve this ? Thanks

Comment: yes. You need to strip out some codes from the object so that the characters would be less than 1800 characters. you can message me at ekanemevidence@gmail.com and we could have a call to resolve this.